# What is the latest ubuntu version that I can use with my PowerMac G5 (non-intel?)

Tags: apple, powerpc

I recently received a old PowerMac G5. I updated its Mac OS operating system to 10.5.8.
I dabbled with Ubuntu with my MacBook and I really liked the experience. I'm trying to find the best version of Ubuntu to install on my PowerMac. I'm also, looking for more precise instructions.  Most of the info that I have found is only relevant to Intel-based Apple computers. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I think from the the [supported hardware page](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/powerpc/hardware-supported.html) the current LTS, 12.04 should be fine.  It says "NewWorld" architecture is supported for the Power Macintosh G5.

[Alternate PowerPC ISO](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/ubuntu-12.04-desktop-powerpc.iso)

Comment: Yes, just be aware that the experience will not be the same as for an Intel CPU.  Some things may not work (such as Adobe Flash, Skype, ...).

Comment: Plus, be aware that not all mirrors mirror PowerPC images. See also [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/237119/88802).