# Can the latest version of Ubuntu run on a Powermac G5?

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the latest ubuntu version that I can use with my PowerMac G5 (non-intel?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197981/what-is-the-latest-ubuntu-version-that-i-can-use-with-my-powermac-g5-non-intel)

Can the latest version of Ubuntu run on a Powermac G5?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

However, from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads/),

> Since 7.04 Ubuntu, PowerPC downloads of Ubuntu are not available on all Ubuntu mirrors. Below you'll find links to the ISOs on the main Ubuntu server, as well as, help on finding mirrors.

A full mirror should include it and have this in the list:

> **Mac (PowerPC) and IBM-PPC (POWER5) desktop image**
>
> For Apple Macintosh G3, G4, and G5 computers, including iBooks and PowerBooks as well as IBM OpenPower machines.

`nl.releases.ubuntu.com` [doesn't](http://nl.releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/), while `cdimage.ubuntu.com` [does](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/quantal/release/).